# ZF2 Query WHERE clause with DATE() for datetime column

Tags: mysql, date, select, zend-framework2, where-clause

I have a column with datetime data type and I want to build a SQL query in Zend Framework2 which compare date part with user input date.

Need to build similar part as DATE(datetime column) = '2014-09-16' with;
$select->where();

would be very grateful if someone could help on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use like this:

```
$date = '2014.05.24';
$select->where('date(expecting_date) = "'.$date.'"');
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use predicate expression for these kind of conditions, like :

```
$select = new \Zend\Db\Sql\Select(table name);
$select->where(new \Zend\Db\Sql\Predicate\Expression('DATE(datetime) = ?', '2014-09-16'));
```