# Convert mysql query to zend query?

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework, zend-framework2

I want to convert following sql query to zend query. How I can convert this mysql query into zend query with zend framework 2?

```
SELECT SUM(amount)
FROM tbl_sale_amount 
WHERE sale_type_id=7459650 AND YEAR(db_add_date) = YEAR(CURDATE());
```

NOTE: Need to fetch sum of amount for current year from tbl_sale_amount.

Thanks

GOT MY ANSWER HERE:
[ZF2 Query WHERE clause with DATE() for datetime column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25886590/zf2-query-where-clause-with-date-for-datetime-column)

Comment: duplicate question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6161370/raw-sql-query-with-zend-framework

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
 $stmt = $db->query('SELECT SUM(amount)
    FROM tbl_sale_amount 
    WHERE sale_type_id= ? AND YEAR(db_add_date) = YEAR(CURDATE()',
                array($sale_type_id)
            );

$result = $stmt->fetchAll();
        $stmt->closeCursor();
        if ($result) {
            return $result;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
```